# How to create a path alias with a query string in the target?

Tags: path-aliases

I want to link `/myownstuff` to `/stuff?owner=myself`

It should at least be possible to do with some module, and with httpd-level configuration, but I don't know how to achieve either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you can do this with the [Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) (it won't provide an alias in its truest form but it will forward you on to the right page.

In `.htaccess` you could a custom RewriteRule before Drupal's main index.php rule:

```
RewriteRule ^myownstuff$ stuff?owner=myself [L,QSA,R=301] # QSA and R=301 are optional here
```

If neither of these work there is a quick and dirty way in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'myownstuff') {
    drupal_goto('stuff', array('query' => array('owner' => 'myself')));
  }
}
```

If you've got more than one path to forward/a pattern etc. you'll have to extend this a bit but the logic will work.

I think the `.htaccess` is probably the best way as it doesn't actually forward on to the URL but masks it internally which I guess is what you're after.

You might also want to look at [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) which I believe you can use to get this kind of functionality...I've not used it before so I can't comment further though.

Comment: Will the .htaccess file be automatically overridden when you update Drupal?

Comment: @MarioAwad Yes it will, if you've got a customised .htaccess file you'll need to replace that separately after the core update

Comment: That's a headache then and maybe it's best to shy away from the .htaccess option and go with the other options you provided. Thanks for answering. Cheers.