# Looking to create a taxonomy term path with a query string

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have seen this question asked over on DO and here, but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer.

[How to create a path alias with a query string in the target?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21934/how-to-create-a-path-alias-with-a-query-string-in-the-target)

I need to able to send a query string when someone clicks on a Taxonomy Tag.

So, I set my tags such as
Things-To-Do/All/[term:name]/?shs_term_node_tid_depth=[term:tid]

Which encodes the string to 
/Things-To-Do/All/arts-culture-history/%3Fshs_term_node_tid_depth%3D612

Which does pull up my view, but of course, doesn't filter.

I have tried creating a custom module, as well as using global redirect, but no luck.

Is this simply not possible? Can I stick something in View Pre-render or something that will unencode the string before it renders.

I have been hitting my head against this problem for a while now and really don't know where to turn.

I should point out that the above answer 'works' but not really with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out.

```
    function cin_rd_init(){

    //first I see if this is a taxonomy page
    if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {

    //then I get the termID from the argument   
    $termid=arg(2);
        $newterm=taxonomy_term_load($termid);

        if(!empty($newterm)){
        $thetermname=str_replace(' ','-',$newterm->name);
        $thetermid=$newterm->tid;   
        $newtermvid=$newterm->vid;

        //Next I check the vocabularyID to see if it should be redirected
        //Important, I also check to see if my parameter string is set already so I don't have an endless redirect.
        if($newtermvid==18 && (!isset($_REQUEST['shs_term_node_tid_depth']))){  
        drupal_goto('/Events/All/'.$thetermname.'/', array('query' => array('shs_term_node_tid_depth' => $thetermid)));
        }
        //I can change the destination and query string depending on the vocab I am using
        if($newtermvid==19 && (!isset($_REQUEST['features']))){ 
        drupal_goto('/Events/All/'.$thetermname.'/', array('query' => array('features[]' => $thetermid)));
        }
} //not empty
} //end if taxonomy
} //end function
```

So now, anyone who goes to a taxonomy term page will either go directly to the term page, unless the term belongs to either of these vocabularies.

If so, then it will redirect those with a query string.